# How can I get seperate list of leap year or not leap year from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code, the code shows output together, but I want to get it separately.
please help me.

```js
//array of years
let yearList = [2000, 2005, 1700, 1996, 2002];
for (let i = 0; i < yearList.length; i++) {

    //condition to check the year is leap year or not
    if (i % 4 == 0 && i % 4 != 100 || i % 400 == 0) {

        var leapYear = yearList[i];
        console.log("these years are leap year: ", leapYear);
    }
    else {

        leapYear = yearList[i];
        console.log("these years are not leap year:", leapYear);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Firstly**, your condition is wrong:

- Check `year` instead of index `i`
- Condition includes 2 parts `(year % 4 == 0 && year % 4 != 100)` and `|| year % 400 == 0`

> A leap year is exactly divisible by 4 except for century years (years
> ending with 00). The century year is a leap year only if it is
> perfectly divisible by 400.

```
//condition to check the year is leap year or not
if (i % 4 == 0 && i % 4 != 100 || i % 400 == 0) {
```

should be

```
if ((yearList[i]% 4 == 0 && yearList[i]% 4 != 100) || yearList[i]% 400 == 0)
```

**Secondly,** you can split the result into an individual array like below

```js
//array of years
let yearList = [2000, 2005, 1700, 1996, 2002];
var leapYearArr = [];
var notLeapYearArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < yearList.length; i++) {
    var year = yearList[i];
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 4 != 100) || year % 400 == 0) {
        leapYearArr.push(year);
    }
    else notLeapYearArr.push(year);
}

console.log("these years are leap year: " + leapYearArr.join(', '));
console.log("these years are not leap year: " + notLeapYearArr.join(', '));
```

**Refactor code** (Of course, *Keep Calm and Refactor Code* ^^! )

```js
let yearList = [2000, 2005, 1700, 1996, 2002];
var isLeapYear = year => (year % 4 == 0 && year % 4 != 100) || (year % 400 == 0);

var result = yearList.reduce((acc, year) => 
            {
               isLeapYear(year) ? acc["LeapYear"].push(year) 
                                : acc["NotLeapYear"].push(year);
               return acc;
            }, {LeapYear: [], NotLeapYear: []});
            
console.log("LeapYears: " + result.LeapYear.join(','));
console.log("NotLeapYears: " + result.NotLeapYear.join(','));
```

Link check leap year online [here](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1532572418)

Comment: @Rony Barua Don't forget to give me an upvote & mark my answer as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future ^^!