# What's wrong with my leapYearTest javascript?

Tags: javascript

What i expected the output would be, e.g. "1997 is not a leap year", but what i got is nothing.
I think the problem in my code is:
I don't know the difference between `console.log` and `return`.

Can someone please point out the errors in my code and the right way to code it please?

```js
const year = prompt();
const msgYes = 'is a leap year';
const msgNo = 'is not a leap year';

if (year % 4 == 0){
    if (year % 100 == 0){
        if (year % 400 == 0){
            console.log(`${year}+ ${msgYes}`); // if /400 = 0
        } else{
            console.log(`${year}+ ${msgNo}`); // if /400 =/= 0 and /100 = 0
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`${year}+ ${msgYes}`); // if /100 =/= 0 and /4 = 0
    }
} else {
    console.log(`${year}+ ${msgNo}`); // if /4 =/= 0
}
```

Comment: It works in the code snippet.

Comment: You mean the code is right?

Comment: Yes try running the code snippet.

Comment: Click the button `Run code snippet` here below your posted snippet and see what happens.

Comment: Can you try to run this in the console? I can see the output in the snippet.

Comment: Nothing was wrong in your code snippet. What kind of output do you expect. `console.log` will print out your message to the developer console.

Comment: oh it works here, but why is it now working on https://js.do/?

Comment: "*I don't know the difference between console.log and return.*" ... one logs in the console (useless for programming, helpful for debugging) and `return` returns the value so you can get that string instead of just reading it in console.

Comment: It works in the browser-console as well - don't know which problem you would be facing here as every case gets its dedicated `console.log`

Comment: You may need this answer in detailed explanation: 
`var isLeapYear = year => (year % 4 == 0 && year % 4 != 100) || (year % 400 == 0);`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822864/how-can-i-get-seperate-list-of-leap-year-or-not-leap-year-from-an-array/65822904#65822904

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, although it could be tidied up a lot.

```js
const year = prompt();
let msg = 'is not a leap year';

if (year % 4 === 0 && (year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 == 0))
  msg = 'is a leap year';

console.log(`${year} ${msg}`);
```

if you're having trouble putting this in to a function then make sure you `return` something.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand about your code, it fails because your "year" is an string comming from the prompt function which returns string. You should parse it to number.

```
const year = parseInt(prompt(), 10);
```

Also you should check if it's a valid number before your if else cascade.

```
if(isNaN(year)) {
    // not an valid number, show error
    console.log(`${year}+ ${msgNo}`);
}
```

Comment: Whether *year* is a string or number is irrelevant since 1) the tests use *year* in an expression with the `%` remainder operator which coerces the result to number, and 2) the comparison uses `==` which would coerce the operands to the same type anyway.